# Now the site is public, are ServerFault database questions going to be migrated across?

Tags: discussion, migration

At the time of posting this, the Server Fault site has [2,646 questions](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) tagged "sql-server".

Should they be migrated across? And if so, should this be an automatic bulk process, or will each individual question need to be flagged for moderator attention? If each question has to get flagged for moderator attention, there's going to be some extremely busy moderators.

Comment: Is the ultimate goal of this site to eventually bring *all* database-related traffic from both SO and SF? I kind of like that SO deals with programming-related questions (including database programming) and that SF deals with server configuration issues (including database servers). Seems like we'll lose that separation if we try to combine both types of questions here, but I don't want to sound opposed to that - just wondering if that is in fact the goal and, if so, what are the reasons behind it? Put another way: what void in SO and SF does this site fill? Should this be its own question?

Comment: Before I ask a new question: what about the related issue of marking questions on DBA as off-topic for migration to Server Fault? I've seen lots of these questions lately. IMHO we need the option to mark as "off-topic -> belongs on another site -> Server Fault". Or should I ask a new question here for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't personally think there is a case for migrating many, or indeed perhaps any, old questions - and this could only be done with the support of the SF community anyway

I think it is more important to try and get awareness raised in the SF and SO communities that we exist and that advanced database questions will be looked after on this site if they are migrated. I've tried (with limited success) to nudge both with question on [mSF](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1855/what-kind-of-database-dba-questions-does-the-sf-community-want-to-keep/1881#1881) and [mSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100507/what-kind-of-database-dba-questions-does-the-so-community-want-to-keep) - please feel free to chime in especially on SO as you have pretty high rep there

Comment: This is correct. If a question is answer-accepted, there's no reason to migrate it. Just leave it be. But for new questions, yes, migration is going to _generally_ be a good idea.

Comment: I think this is exactly the right way to approach this; kudos.

Comment: You guys are confusing me. I just used stackoverflow for hard db/programming stuff and serverfault for easier database/config stuff. Now I have to check 3 places. Why does there have to be so much choice?

Comment: @IBC judging by the question you asked on SF, I think you'll find yourself at home here on dba.se soon enough. Unless you are asking really basic SQL (which would migrate to SO), I think we have a lot to offer here on anything else DB related